# Virtual Host with MAMP Not Found OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, mamp, virtualhost

These are the things I've done to set up a virtual host with a server name "test.local" for some local development. I have added to MAMP's httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8888

<VirtualHost *:8888>
ServerName test.local
DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public
<Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have uncommented httpd-vhosts.conf in MAMPS httpd.conf so that it is included.

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And I have added 127.0.0.1 test.local to the bottom of my Mac's hosts file.

As far as I can tell from other stackoverflow questions and tutorials, I am following all the right steps, but I am still getting "Page Not Found" when I navigate to http://test.local

I'm in China using a VPN to access most websites and I realized that the VPN could be causing trouble so I have quit that. I tried changing the port of MAMP to listen on to 80 as one stackoverflow question suggested but that did not work.

If I go to localhost:8888/test/public it does work, but I really need a virtual host to work for development.

Does anyone have any other ideas for what might be going on?

Comment: This probably goes without asking, but did you restart Apache after creating the virtual host entry?

Comment: Yup. Restarted MAMP servers. Also tried restarting Mac's built in apache server doing sudo apachectl restart. Tried it with Mac server on and off (did sudo apachectl stop). But I'm assuming that the Mac apache server should be off because MAMP is acting as the server. I'm not entirely sure on that, I'm new to LAMP development

Comment: You are correct in your assumption that the Mac server should be off whilst using MAMP. Hmmm... That is quite perplexing though, especially since you can access it via local host. Have you tried pinging test.local from the Terminal?

Comment: Wait I need to correct myself, when I navigate to "http://localhost:8888", I get the index.html from "Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public" folder. If I navigate to "localhost:8888/test/public" I get a 404. If I ping test.local I get an Unkown host error message.

Comment: The 404 on the localhost:8888 suggests that the DocumentRoot declaration in the httpd.conf may not be pointing to the document root on your server. The unknown host suggests something is wrong in the virtual host config. The Ping error indicates the mapping in your /etc/hosts may be in the wrong place in the file. If you change the log level to debug and restart the server, are there any messages in the error or access logs from startup and then after attempting to access the site both ways?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue with my iMac. My workhorse Macbook Air has no issues, but trying to get it transferred and working on the iMac is falling flat. Where do I initiate those logs @mifi79? Thanks

Comment: The LogLevel directive in your httpd.conf, which should be located in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf. If you are using MAMP, you'll need to right-click on the MAMP icon in Applications and select "Show package contents..." And find it in there. Here is a link to the Apache docs with the valid log options:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel